# Instrumentation and control engineering

Tags: english-to-german

I study "Instrumentation and Control Engineering", one of the electronical sub majors. What is the name of my major in German?

Comment: @whoever downvoted this question: Nafiseh is a new contributor so you should write a comment to tell him/her what you consider inappropriate regarding this question.

Comment: how about that there is no sign what so ever of own work put into answering the question?! This is what is often called a "do-it-for-me" question here on SE

Comment: It depends on, exactly what I learning and where.

Comment: @derbender that's most likely the reason, however, a new contributor might not be aware of that - therefore it is better to tell the newbie what is bad about the question instead of just downvoting without comment.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf yeah its a bummer that the code of conduct that contains this type of information is not a must read for every newbie before he is allowed to post anything...

Comment: @Volker Well, I believe it's better to tell them with a final close vote, at least this counts more than a comment from a single user, and I don't want to be drawn in lengthy arguing with the OP about why their question is _off-topic_.

Comment: @derbender Well, there>'s a tooltip with the DV button, every (even new users) might inspect, to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 3):

"Mess- und Regelungstechnik" is about the closest that you can express in german in a reasonable short fashion although I would recommend asking a dictionary first next time